# Graph $r=3-3\sin\ (2\theta) $ and find the area of one of the loops.

Tags: calculus

I'm just looking for clarification if I am setting up the problem correctly. I know that $$A=(1/2)\int_{[a,b]}r^2 d(\theta).$$ For this problem, to find the bounds, I need to know where $r=0$, which would be at $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ if we are just looking at the lobe that lies mostly in the second quadrant. So my integral should be $$(1/2)\int_{[\pi/4, 5\pi/4]}(3-3\sin\ (2\theta))^2 \ d(\theta).$$ Correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.